# MSI uninstallation fails after "complete successfull"

Tags: windows-installer, installation, rollback

There is subsequent msi uninstall launched after parent installation complete. It was working but at some point it started to fail subsequent uninstall. According to log it completes successfully but after that Rollback is initiated. It restores installation back. I suspect the reason may be in pending reboot flag raised by parent installer.

```
MSI (s) (F8:94) [11:42:04:549]: Product: *productname* 64-bit -- Removal completed successfully.

MSI (s) (F8:94) [11:42:04:549]: Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: *productname* 64-bit. Product Version: 14.3. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: *manufacturer* Software, Inc.. Removal success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (F8:94) [11:42:04:549]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (F8:94) [11:42:04:549]: MainEngineThread is returning 0
MSI (s) (F8:C8) [11:42:04:564]: RESTART MANAGER: Previously shut down applications have been restarted.
MSI (s) (F8:C8) [11:42:04:564]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1224564034,LangId=1033,Platform=589824,ScriptType=2,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=*productname* 64-bit)
MSI (s) (F8:F4) [11:42:04:658]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1],CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1])
```

I tried passing DISABLEROLLBACK=1 on uninstall but it does not seem to work :/
Passing public property would be the most convenient way.

Disabling rollback definitely helps, i tried setting "\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer" "DisableRollback" to "1" and uninstall works fine.

Is there any other properties i couldn't find? I would prefer not to alter customer's environment disabling rollback in registry.

Comment: Updating subsequent msi is not convenient due to it fails on uninstall and it will take effect for following installations but not for previously installed.

Comment: Looks like its something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52e84579-5840-4ba9-b1a2-ecb0df392952/msi-uninstall-error-sxsuninstallca-return-value-3?forum=winformssetup
problem caused by SxsUninstallCA which is executed after InstallFinalize

Comment: You should post the entire log somewhere, not just the parts that seem relevant to you. That section of log looks pretty much like the end of any uninstall log. You should also add more detail about exactly how you are doing a "subsequent msi uninstall launched after parent installation complete"